# Can I replace a 2-gang light switch with a Combo 3 Gang 4 Up / Down & Sideways Toggle Light Switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

Is this possible? Obviously, I have to cut out the drywall to accommodate the new box. Currently this is the set-up: [image: 2 pole light switch image]

Ultimately, I need this outlet to contain: 2 light switches and 2 120V receptacles:
[Switch Plate Config.](http://www.kyleswitchplates.com/combo-3-gang-4-up-down-sideways-toggle-light-switch-plates/) (I was unable to find a pic for the outlet, could only find switch plate pic).
The breaker for the existing switch is 15 amps. Also on the same breaker, a duplex 120V receptacle.

Comment: What do you mean by AC switch? A thermostat? Something controlling a window AC?

Comment: From that switch, you are in North America... but "AC switch" is not a term in common usage here. Jargon terms are difficult to use well; please explain in plain English.  Also, please review this about the meaning of "2-gang" etc. and then edit your question as needed.    http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11654/what-does-1-gang-2-gang-and-so-forth-mean-when-talking-about-electrical-bo  It may be possible to do what you want without hacking drywall, but we need to be clear.

Comment: Thanks Harper--indeed in USA and will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean one duplex receptacle (2 plugs) or two duplex receptacles (four plugs)?

Comment: Also, do you know if there's a neutral at this location?

Comment: If I read this correctly, you want to make this a 2-gang box (double its size to accommodate the switch you have plus 2 outlets) or a 3-gang box (triple the size with 4 switches and 2 outlets.) Either way, you will need to cut the drywall and install the larger box, plus some wire with pigtails to the outlets. You won't necessarily need to run more wire unless you need another circuit. You can pig tail off the hot side of your switch to power the outlets, or even use a switch controlled outlet.

Comment: This looks like a kitchen setup from the back splash or that is what it looks like to me. Usually when I wire kitchen appliances like this I bring the hot to the switches. You will need both a neutral and hot in the box to add outlets without adding more wiring.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks so much for taking the time. I'm gonna tackle this next weekend and will report  back. I may have additional questions.

Comment: @EdBeal I hope you have started wiring neutral in switch loops, it's a good habit, it helps people in this situation or smart switches.

Comment: I do install neutrals since code started requiring it. Most of the time they are just covered with a wire nut. In the last few years I have installed quite a few smart switches that had to have new wires run so I understand the requirement for the neutral.

Answer (score 2):

This is a single gang 2 switch unit. By removing the single gang box and installing a double gang box (old work box would be the easiest to install). You could use the same switches and add a duplex receptacle. A standard  double gang outlet cover will finish it.